# zsh + Hyper.js + Windows 10 = blue font?

Tags: zsh, hyper

I've got a problem where my Hyper terminal emulator keeps changing my zsh shell text to blue. This doesn't happen on WSL.

**WSL:**

[image]

**Hyper.js:**

[image]

Changing **hyper.js** 'cyan' to #FFFFFF obviously makes it white but I don't want to fix it that way. For some reason, zsh let's Hyper know that it needs to render cyan/blue.

This happens after I reinstall hyper.js and clear the roaming/local appfolders:

**Cleared:**

[image]

I've been staring at this issue for way too long, tried everything I can and know. I have no idea where to look now, since it doesn't happen in WSL (Bash/Ubuntu for Windows).

Is there any way I can debug zsh or Hyper to tell me why it's turning blue/cyan?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please insert your source code and don't reference to external images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Issue, you need to reset your CMD colors before using Hyper, check [this issue](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1706#issuecomment-302873966) for more information.

**Solution:** 
Go to [this link](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/401170-command-prompt-restore-default-personalization-settings.html)  download **Console_Defaults_win10.reg**, execute it and then open Hyper.

Enjoy.